# Hide the window frame around image plotted with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to show a picture but I want to hide the window frame.

I tried the code `frameon=False` in `plt.figure()` but the window frame is still there. Just the background color turns to grey.

Here is the code and running result. The picture was showing with the window even I add the "frameon=False" in the code.

[image: Link for issue screenshot]

Comment: I want the QR code can be showed on screen only. No window element around it. Thx.

Comment: The hardware is raspberry pi 3b and the operation system is raspbain. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frameon` suppresses the figure frame. What you want to do is show the figure canvas in a frameless window, which cannot be managed from within matplotlib, because the window is an element of the GUI that shows the canvas. Whether it is possible to suppress the frame and how to do that will depend on the operating system and the matplotlib backend in use.

Let's consider the **tk backend**.

```
import matplotlib
# make sure Tk backend is used
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# turn navigation toolbar off
plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'

# create a figure and subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2,2))
#remove margins
fig.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)
# turn axes off
ax.axis("off")
# show image
im = plt.imread("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/QRCode.png")
ax.imshow(im)

# remove window frame
fig.canvas.manager.window.overrideredirect(1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! I also can use plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.wm_geometry("400x400+50+1000") to set the picture size and position.