# Remove title bar using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have a question about how to show the `cv2.imshow()` without a title bar.

This is what I have now, it still has a minimize, maximize, and close button. I want to remove them.
[My cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd5bn.png)
Any solution will be very helpful.

I already tried [Python OpenCV - remove title bar, toolbar, and status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095446/python-opencv-remove-title-bar-toolbar-and-status-bar) but it didn't work.

I think its outdated.

This is the code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pickle


width = 640
height = 480
threshold =0.0
maxProb = 0
resultClass = ""


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cam.set(3,width)
cam.set(4,height)



pickle_in = open("model_trained.101sgd","rb")
model = pickle.load(pickle_in)


def PreProcessing(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    img = img/255 
    return img
```

while True:
success, imgOriginal = cam.read()
img = np.asarray(imgOriginal)

```
img = cv2.resize(img,(32,32))
img = PreProcessing(img)
cv2.imshow("Processed Image",img)
img = img.reshape(1,32,32,1)

#Predict
classIndex = int(model.predict_classes(img))
#print(classIndex)
predictions = model.predict(img)
#print(predictions)
probVal  = np.amax(predictions)


# if probVal > maxProb:
#     maxProb = probVal 
#     resultClass = classIndex


if probVal >threshold:
    cv2.putText(imgOriginal,str(classIndex) + " " +str(probVal),(50,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,
            1,(0,0,255),1 )
    
cv2.imshow("Original Image", imgOriginal)
    

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

Comment: The only way won't have a title bar is in full screen view. OpenCV's HighGUI module is quite basic, just a convenience for prototyping, so you can display an image, maybe with a few sliders added. If you want anything more, you need to implement your own UI, using a proper UI toolkit.

Comment: PLEASE DONT YELL. Also, use matplotlib (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503806/hide-the-window-frame-around-image-plotted-with-matplotlib)

Comment: Can you add code of yours?

Comment: sorry for the yell, i already add my code

Comment: thankyou for the recommendations Dan Masek,